# c# program pinging computers and get bluescreen

Tags: c#, .net

When I start the program the form freezes and sometimes i get bluescreen and the computer restarts.

I am running Windows 7 Enterprise 64 and have Intel core i5 2.60 GHz and 8 GBs of RAM

If anyone know what the problem is that whold be very helpful thanks.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //IP variables
        string localIP = GetLocalIPAddress();
        string[] targetIP = new string[255];

        //Init
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping pingSender = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
        options.DontFragment = true;

        //Variables
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                //textbox.text example: 10.20.18.
                //i = 0 > 255
                targetIP[i] = textBox2.Text + i;      

                //send ping
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(targetIP[i], timeout, buffer, options);

                //if reply is successfull
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText("Address: " + reply.Address + "\t ms: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get a bluescreen from a .NET program that exclusively uses managed APIs, the problem ***is not with the program***. You have some sort of hardware/driver problem that needs fixing. Diagnose the bluescreen, not your program. As such, this question isn't appropriate for SO.

Comment: What is the STOP message on the bsod?  This seems likely to be an issue with your adapter drivers if anything.

Comment: I just ran it, It happened when i stoped the program and sometimes it happens after some time i press the button

Comment: I guess that the pingSender is a disposable object as it should use windows resources. Use the pingSender.Dispose() method, and create a new instance a each stpe of the loop

Comment: Sometimes it does not crash and it works fine

Comment: it should be disposed but not disposing it will not cause a bsod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ping object is disposable... So use it to release windows resources.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                using (System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping pingSender = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping())

                {
                    //textbox.text example: 10.20.18.
                    //i = 0 > 255
                    targetIP[i] = textBox2.Text + i;

                    //send ping
                    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(targetIP[i], timeout, buffer, options);

                    //if reply is successfull
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        textBox1.AppendText("Address: " + reply.Address + "\t ms: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "\n");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Do you really believe that this will fix a BSOD? A .NET program that doesn't use unsafe code should never be able to trigger a BSOD. This is not a programming issue. It's a hardware/driver issue, and the OP should concentrate on this.

Comment: .NEt is not using only managed memory... Eveything that is font, image, file handling, and network resources (wininet.dll ?) are getting unmanaged windows resources, that need to be disposed. Otherwise your windows resources table will blow up, and eventually it can crash your computer.

Comment: That's a guess at best. The answer here is to diagnose the BSOD, then make conclusions.

Comment: A intermediary conclusion is that whatever you do, if an object is implementing IDisposable, it should be disposed after usage... otherwise the behavior of your application is uncertain.

Comment: @spender : 'a .NET program that exclusively uses managed APIs". And that is not true anyway.

Comment: I'd go further and say that *any* Windows user mode program shouldn't be able to cause a BSOD. For a .NET program to do so simply by failing to dispose of a single (or even a few hundred) `Ping` instances would be incredibly unlikely. Likely this is caused by a bad network driver, memory issues or some hardware failure and OP should concentrate their efforts there instead.

Comment: Give a try then... Start and restart the program till it crashes... under Windows 7 :-)